# Userform caption won't display in titlebar

Tags: excel, userform, excel-2013, caption, vba

In Excel 2013, when I create a UserForm in the VBE, the default caption "UserForm1" shows in the VBE just as it should up in the title bar. But when I run the form, ***no title gets displayed*** in the title bar. It is blank.

When I attempt to change the caption in Properties, the change shows in the title bar of the VBE in Design Mode, but again when I run the Form, the title is blank.

When I attempt to change the caption in the Form Initialization procedure and then run the form, again no title gets displayed.

There is *no code* in the workbook (unless I attempt the change in the Initialization procedure as described above). This is in a new workbook, new Userform. This problem occurs with any new workbook, or any existing workbook.

The installation of Excel 2013 is the only installation that has ever existed on this computer. It was installed with the full package of MS Office 2013 365 software. The computer is new within the last 8 weeks and had no previous installations.

Two people from this website have opened the file in Excel 2010. Both have confirmed that the caption shows properly in the title bar. I would appreciate anyone with Excel 2013 taking a look at this.

**Interesting note:** I *am* able to create UserForms properly in MS Word 2013. The titles show properly when I create and run them in Word. I saved a test form from Word, then imported it into Excel. It again showed the title properly in the VBE, but again not when I ran the form. When I re-open it in Word, the title still shows properly.

**New info:** I added a command button to the form which, when clicked, would pop up a message box telling me the form.caption. It *does* tell me the proper caption, as if it's there, despite the fact that the title bar does not show it. I verified that the forecolor of the form is set to ButtonText, like other items on the form. And again...the same form showed the title just fine in Word, as well as in the VBE of Excel.

Here is a link to screenshots of the problem and a sample file:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=25D7A35A46EFD389!11701&authkey=!AL3-XIdcE3_nabo&ithint=folder%2cpng

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your system running with large fonts enabled? Just a guess that maybe that is interfering.

Comment: aphoria, that was an interesting idea. I have Windows 8.1 (ick), and did make some adjustments. In "Appearance and Personalization\Display, the slider for all things in general is to the far left (smallest). However, I did adjust some individual items. "Title bars" in particular is set to 9 (might even be the default), so that's actually still pretty small. I changed it to 6 to see if it affected anything (for the UserForm), but it did not. I really didn't expect it to since it shows properly in Word, but it was worth a try. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Looking at your screenshots, the font sizes of the **Project - VBAProject** and **Properties - UserForm1** sections of the VBA Editor look really large...maybe related?

Comment: aphoria, the thing is, the settings are the same in Word. I've placed screenshots at the link of the Word VBE with the form as well as the running form from Word, and as you can see the setup is the same.

Comment: In the form load event, add a messagebox that displays the form Caption. This should at least tell us if the Caption is actually blank or just not being displayed.

Comment: Good idea, aphoria. Using debug.print I was able to verify that the caption does exist during the form initialization event the way it's supposed to.

Comment: I also added a commandbutton to the form so I could msgbox the caption ***while the form is running***, and the caption is ***also*** intact. The msgbox did in fact tell me the caption it supposedly is displaying. This caused me to examine the ForeColor property of the form, and it's set to ButtonText as it should be. No other item on the form (buttons, etc.) have a font color issue, and they're all set to the same ButtonText ForeColor.

Comment: If you want to make sure someone sees your comments, refer them to as @username, then they will get a notification.

Comment: I opened your sample file too (on Windows 7) and it worked fine. Aren't all title bars centered in Windows 8? I don't have a W8 machine nearby to check.

Comment: @aphoria I don't know if all title bars are centered or not. That was an observation by someone who opened the file in Excel 2010. I know the title is centered in my VBE. Which version of Excel did you use to open the file?

Comment: I opened in Windows 7 & Excel 2010. I think _all_ title bars are centered in Windows 8, not just in Excel on Windows 8.

Comment: Still looking for suggestions. No solutions as yet.

Comment: After weeks of dabbling, I have stumbled onto a solution. My forms now show titles. It will take a bit more investigating when I find time, but it appears that the issue was Windows 8.1 related. I did some adjusting of my Appearances settings...fonts, themes, colors, etc...and suddenly the titles are now showing. The only thing I can say is that I had been running an Aerolite theme package. My initial suspicion is that it was somehow being caused by that. I've now reverted to a theme downloaded from the MS website and the titles are all fine. One thing is certain: it's not an Excel issue.

Comment: Also, while I said it's not an Excel issue, it should be noted that the problem did not present itself when I opened the same forms in MS Word. It would seem there is a difference between the way Word relates with the OS and the way Excel does, so there *is* something inherent to Excel that is related to this issue. But clearly the issue can be resolved through the adjustment of settings in Windows. It seems, however, that Microsoft could make some adjustments in Excel as well.